# Astronomer/Apache Airflow - File Sensor Does Not Trigger

Tags: python, file, airflow, sensors

I'm an Airflow newbie, and to test my knowledge, I'm attempting to write a simple file and test for its presence in Airflow. Here's the code snippet...

```
def _downloading_data(**kwargs):
    f = open('my_file.txt', 'w')
    f.write('my_data')
    f.close()

with DAG(dag_id='simple_dag', default_args=default_args, start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None, catchup=False) as dag:
    
    downloading_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='downloading_data',
        python_callable=_downloading_data,
    )
    
    waiting_for_data = FileSensor(
        task_id='waiting_for_data',
        filepath = 'my_file.txt',
        fs_conn_id='fs_default',
    )
```

In this case, the sensor never triggers. I can only assume this is because Docker is writing the file to a place I don't know about. I have set up the connection using the admin console, so I think that's okay at least.

I attempted to change the filepath parameter and file name in the Python function to an absolute path (ex: c:\test\my_file.txt) but that resulted in the error "No such file".

Comment: Note that if you're an Astronomer customer you can reach out to support :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is with your `fs_default` Connection. It's working as expected after I set up the `fs_default` Connection using the `File (path)` Connection type with the `extra` field set to...

```json
{
  "path": "/usr/local/airflow"
}
```

Note that this is not typically a recommended use case. Airflow is often run in a distributed environment, so if task A downloads a file, chances are task B will run on a different worker and won't have access to `my_file.txt`.

[image]